# Automate Toad Edge Query to run and email results

Tags: mysql, automation, toad

I currently run a manual query every morning on Toad Edge, and am looking to automate it to run at 9:00 AM every morning and email me a result of the query. Only using the trial version as well, not sure if possible without the licensed version.

Below are key points to that I am looking for:

- Automate query for toad edge specified time (9:00 AM)
- Email results to specified email

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Toad Edge is delivered with command line tool, that can be called from command line or integrated with Jenkins:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Continuous+Integration+With+Toad+Edge+Plugin

This command line tool is available also for trial users on:
https://support.quest.com/toad-edge/1.2.1/download-new-releases

In Toad Edge you can create all needed files for Jenkins plugin, and then use Jenkins to do everyday script execution
[CI/CD wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjh5p.png)

And in Jenkins configure build step to send an email.

More information about Toad Edge and Jenkins here:
https://community.toadworld.com/products/toad-edge/b/weblog/archive/2018/01/18/how-to-create-an-quot-empty-database-quot-project-in-jenkins-with-the-help-of-toad-edge